Urgent Help Needed: Accidental File Deletion in Magento and Composer Issues
I’m facing a serious problem with my Magento website, and I’d really appreciate any help or advice you can offer.
A few days ago, Liquidweb, my hosting deleted files from the main directory of my site (/home/wwwdos9/public_html/shopmami) instead of just clearing the cache files. The rm -rf command was mistakenly run on the main directory. Since then, the site has been throwing errors, specifically the following one: "Autoload error: Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory."
Unfortunately, the available automated backup was overwritten just before I realized the issue, so I don’t have a recent backup of the site. The hosting support team has tried to help me, but we haven’t had much success.
Here are some additional details about the environment:
Magento (unsure of the exact version).
VPS server with outdated OS and WHM (without support for some modern tools like Composer 2).
I’ve tried reinstalling Composer and fixing the autoload issue, but I’m getting errors related to authentication keys for Composer repositories.
I don’t have any other available backups on the server, although there might be some stored locally or in other development environments.
My questions are:
Has anyone experienced something similar? Is there any way to restore or reconfigure Magento without a full backup?
What critical Magento files should be in the main directory for the site to function properly?
Any advice on how to deal with the Composer issue or how to install a functional version on an older server?
If I can’t restore the site, is there any way to reinstall or rebuild the site using the existing files and databases?
I’m open to any suggestions or recommendations. I’m really stuck at this point and would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance!

Check if your vendor directory is intact or not, from the error that you stated it seems like it's not, so you need to run composer update or install again which will restore your vendor directory if the composer.lock file is still there otherwise you need to manually restore the files from the repo

The composer.lock file is present, but I'm using Composer version 1.10.17. I understand that this could be limiting the installation or update of modern dependencies. Perhaps the best option is to upgrade Composer to version 2 to ensure compatibility with the latest dependencies and restore the vendor directory correctly.
I will proceed with the Composer upgrade to version 2 and then run composer install to see if that resolves the issue.

Is this you prod site ? What about version control ? last release ? you could technically rebuild site in local system and deploy or copy over files. If you were on older version, composer 1 will still work. its not late to preserve db copy if you haven't already, which can help you rebuild system again.
You will likely to have issues though, because you might have lost env.php which has your crypt key, which invalidate bunch of config and you need to reconfigure again.

If you have your basic files but the packages are failing to install using composer (v1 or v2 - does not matter) due to missing credentials, you are missing the "auth.json" file which composer reads to get the credentials for the specific repositories.
The main one is the Magento one which you should be able to get from the Magento developer portal. Enter to https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/
Login -> My profile -> My products / Access keys
From there get the Public Key and Private Key to configure composer with those values when requested.
If you have third party extension, you should get them from the vendor portal (usually in the install instructions of the extension).
You can get more info about Auth on composer here
